# How to find all edges from Root node in recursive way?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

There is a list which contains the following data about tree edges,

```
alist=[[Root, A],[Root, B],[Root,C],[A,D],[A,E],[D,F]...[]]
```

I want to find out all paths from 'Root' node to leaf node. Also, some edges in *alist* can never be traveled from 'Root' node.

I prefer to use recursion. Could someone give me a tip for that?

**[Edit]**

I expect the output just like alist, but all orphan edges are deleted.

Comment: Create the *transitive closure* of the tree.  The edges you seek will be direct edges from Root in the transitive closure.

Comment: Are you looking for edges or paths?  Maybe you can show an example output.  And, your attempts so far.

Comment: Definetely add an expected input/output and what you have tried so far. I don't quite get what you're asking.

Comment: @talaria, Sorry If my question is confusing. I try to use recursion to find out all  paths from 'Root' node to leaf node.  I rarely use recursive code so I need some help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: That said, you need to start with doing some on-line research.  You may need a few terms to help, such as graph, path, traverse, etc.

Comment: Is "leaf" a particular node name, like **Root**, or is it just any node with no further paths to take?